# Rolling operation over rows by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to do roll an operation over the rows of a `data.table` by group.

In this example below, I want to get the `values` of each `id` in 2017 and subtract from the value in 2014. The solution should not involve reshaping the data. It has to  create a new column that will show how the value of each id changed between the two years.

#### reproducible example

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table( id=rep(letters[1:4],2),
                  values=c(11,22,33,44, 1,2,3,4),
                  year=c(rep(2014,4), rep(2017,4)))

#>  dt
#>     id values year
#>  1:  a     11 2014
#>  2:  b     22 2014
#>  3:  c     33 2014
#>  4:  d     44 2014
#>  5:  a      1 2017
#>  6:  b      2 2017
#>  7:  c      3 2017
#>  8:  d      4 2017
```

Expected output:

```
#> dt
#>    id values year result
#> 1:  a     11 2014     10
#> 2:  b     22 2014     20
#> 3:  c     33 2014     30
#> 4:  d     44 2014     40
#> 5:  a      1 2017     10
#> 6:  b      2 2017     20
#> 7:  c      3 2017     30
#> 8:  d      4 2017     40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is farily simple using

```
dt[, result := values[year == 2014] - values[year == 2017], by = id]
#   id values year result
#1:  a     11 2014     10
#2:  b     22 2014     20
#3:  c     33 2014     30
#4:  d     44 2014     40
#5:  a      1 2017     10
#6:  b      2 2017     20
#7:  c      3 2017     30
#8:  d      4 2017     40
```

Another option (less explicit) is with `diff`:

```
dt[order(-year), result := diff(values), by = id]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(result = values[year == 2014] - values[year == 2017])
```