# Using mutate and group_by to roll an operation over rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
country       year  sales
--------------------------
Afghanistan   1950   30
Afghanistan   1951   35
Albania       1950    0
Albania       1951    5
total         1950   30
total         1951   40
```

I want to generate a new column, ratio, which is the ratio of sales for any given country-year combination to the total for that year. So the output should be:

```
country       year  sales  ratio
---------------------------------
Afghanistan   1950   30     1
Afghanistan   1951   35     0.875
Albania       1950    0     0
Albania       1951    5     0.125
total         1950   30     1
total         1951   40     1
```

I'd like to use tidyverse (which I am somewhat new to) to accomplish this, but I'm still somewhat confused about how to use mutate and group_by to accomplish this (or even if that is the best way to go about this task in general).

I tried unsuccessfully to use the advice given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890434/rolling-operation-over-rows-by-group-in-data-table). What I have tried is:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
group_by(year) %>%
mutate(ratio = sales[country]/sales[country == "total"])
```

But this generates a column called ratio full of NAs. Do I need to use a loop or something else? I'm somewhat new to R and I will admit I have avoided loops up until now. Looking over documentation on loops, I couldn't quite think of how I would use one to run over each country-year combination and generate a new column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group by country and then divide sales by maximum of sales - which is `total`, I suppose.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = sales / max(sales))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   year [2]
#  country      year sales ratio
#  <chr>       <int> <int> <dbl>
#1 Afghanistan  1950    30 1    
#2 Afghanistan  1951    35 0.875
#3 Albania      1950     0 0    
#4 Albania      1951     5 0.125
#5 total        1950    30 1    
#6 total        1951    40 1
```

---

In `base R`

```
transform(df, ratio = ave(sales, year, FUN = function(x) x / max(x)))
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ratio := sales / max(sales), by = year][]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Albania", 
"Albania", "total", "total"), year = c(1950L, 1951L, 1950L, 1951L, 
1950L, 1951L), sales = c(30L, 35L, 0L, 5L, 30L, 40L)), .Names = c("country", 
"year", "sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's so obvious but I would have never thought to use max for this. Thank you so much.